# In nested if statement form's if statement not work

Tags: php, html

```
if($media=="pet")
{   

if($pressure=="bar")
{

        if($f_req=="ltr/m")
    {

    $kvreq=$flowreq/16.666666667*16.6667/(pow(($presur*1/0.98066/660*1000),0.5));
        echo "<b>KV Required:-   </b>$kvreq ";  
        ?>
            <br/><br/>
        <?php
    if($kvreq > 14 and $kvreq <= 38){

            $minOrfice=10;
                $n_kv=38;
                $maxOrfice=7;
                echo "<b>Minimum Orfice Required:- </b>$minOrfice";?>
                </br></br>
                <?php
                $n_kv1=($n_kv/16.66667*(pow($presur*1/0.98066/660*1000,0.5)))*16.666666667;
                echo "$n_kv1 <b>liter/min</b>";?>
                </br></br>
                <?php
                echo "The Max Flow at $maxOrfice orfice";?>
                </br></br>
                <?php
                $maxfo=((14/16.66667)*(pow(($presur*1/0.98066/660)*1000,0.5)))*16.666666667;
                echo "$maxfo <b>liter/min</b>";?>       

                <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                         <input name="chkb1"  type="checkbox" />

                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="chk_btn" id="chk_btn"/>
                </form> 
            <?php   
                if(isset($_POST['chk_btn'])){                           

                    echo "$abc";    

                }                   

}       
}
}
}

...................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Comment: i haven't tried this `if($kvreq > 14 and $kvreq <= 38)` in my works..

Comment: here some part of code mine.. in this code last if statement not work..

Comment: can you define where exactly? `if` will not work when you didn't meet the condition

Comment: if(isset($_POST['chk_btn'])){                           

                    echo "$abc";    

                }

Comment: using `if(isset($_GET['chk_btn']))` should work , did you try it after you submit the form?

Comment: if(isset($_GET['chk_btn'])) yes after submit the form i want to print any msg..

Comment: did you try putting `if(isset($_GET['chk_btn']))` at the top of your page see if it display?

Comment: yes if its putting top of the page then it display..

Comment: but i want to put inner side..

Answer (score 1):

your form method is GET while you're attemptig to get POST data

change this:

```
if(isset($_GET['chk_btn']))
```

Comment: I tried the code and it works. Pardon me if I ask: did you press the 'submit' button? Also: maybe you'll get a Notice if you don't set `$abc` variable, if so set `$abc` or change your code into `echo "abc"` and not `echo "$abc"`

Comment: sory itz my mistake, $abc is not variable i just printing msg abc or any else.. but my code is not work if i put abc instead of $abc

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($_POST['chk_btn']))` to `if(isset($_GET['chk_btn']))` should fix the problem but OP refuse that still cannot display any text.

I suspect that upon submitting the the form again in the page it lose the value of `$media`, `$pressure` and so on there it never pass the if statements and never proceed on next process

```
if($media=="pet")
{   
  if($pressure=="bar")
  {
    if($f_req=="ltr/m")
      {
```

Comment: ya after submit the form blank page display.. have any idea whats the solution.. bcus i want to fire query in that if statement..

Comment: What's the event on how do you get this value? `if($media=="pet")` and so on? also changed this `isset($_POST['chk_btn'])` to `$_GET` as the above mentioned